# How do I reproduce this with css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build this image [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSyGx.png]

using css.

Item 2 is the big content area and item 1 and 3 are laid in 2. Item I will display a list of friends and is scrollable while item 3 should be fixed, so a user shouldn't scroll down to find it because that would be where they'll enter text. Also the whole area should cover stretch from the top to the bottom but with a width of 900px(item 2)

I've been trying to get this done for the past few hours but I can't get just area 1 to scroll without it affecting area 2 and 3 plus I can't get area 3 to stay in place.

This is what I tried

```
.imchatbox {
position:fixed;
border-right:1px solid #cccccc;
border-left:1px solid #cccccc;
width:900px;
height:100%;
left:15%;
right:50%;
overflow:scroll
background-color: #FFFFFF;
top:0px; 
padding:20px;
padding-top:50px;
bottom: 0px;



}

.imchatlist{
border-right:1px solid #cccccc;
border-left:1px solid #cccccc;
width:300px;
top:0px;
height:100%
background-color: #cccccc;

overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;

}

.imtextarea{

border-right:1px solid #cccccc;
border-left:1px solid #cccccc;
border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
width:600px;
height:20%;
left:301px;
}
```

Where imchatbox is 2, imchatlist is 1 and im textarea is 3. But yeah it doesn't work, can someone help me out?

Comment: We need to see your HTML as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this is to wrap the left side and the right side in individual wrappers that are both floated. The left one should be set to `overflow-y: auto;`. Then, in the left side, put another div that is set to `height: auto`.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/5TtBX/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot Jake! What you gave me set me up. I'm not too verse with css so even though I knew what floating was in theory, it didn't occur to me to use. Anyway thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score -1):

```
.imchatbox {
position:absolute;
border-right:1px solid #cccccc;
border-left:1px solid #cccccc;
width:85%;;
top:0px;
height:80%;
left:15%;
right:85%;
overflow:scroll;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
padding:20px;
padding-top:50px;
}

.imchatlist{
position:absolute;
border-right:1px solid #cccccc;
border-left:1px solid #cccccc;
left=0px;
top:0px;
width:15%;
height:100%;
background-color: #cccccc;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
}

.imtextarea{
position:absolute;
border-right:1px solid #cccccc;
border-left:1px solid #cccccc;
border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
width:85%;
height:20%;
left:15%;
bottom:0px;
}
```